# How to the encoding for TaggedCorpusReader? Default argument handling

Tags: python, nltk

I'm using the TaggedCorpusReader from Python's NLTK. I want to read a utf8 encoded file. To do so, I wanted to chance the default encoding 'none' (regarding the documentation) to 'utf8'. Therefore I need to hand over the default arguments reaching the encoding argument.

```
__init__(self, root, fileids, sep='/', 
        word_tokenizer=WhitespaceTokenizer(pattern='\\s+',
                   gaps=True, discard_empty=T..., 
        sent_tokenizer=RegexpTokenizer(pattern='\n', 
        gaps=True, discard_empty=True, f..., 
        para_block_reader=<function read_blankline_block at 0x132be70>, 
        encoding=None, tag_mapping_function=None)
```

This is the definition from [googlecode](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/corpus/reader/tagged.html#TaggedCorpusReader).

What I did now, I called the constructor like this:

```
TaggedCorpusReader('.' ,  filelist, '/', 
        WhitespaceTokenizer(u'\s+', True, True, 56), 
        RegexpTokenizer('n', True, True, 56), 
        <function read_blankline_block at 0x5b731b8>, 
        'utf8', None)
```

Then I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nlpenhg.py", line 2, in <module>
    from BonnerCorpus import *
  File "path/code/BonnerCorpus.py", line 27
    self.corpus = TaggedCorpusReader('.' ,  filelist, '/', WhitespaceTokenizer(u'\s+', True, True, 56), RegexpTokenizer('n', True, True, 56), <function read_blankline_block at 0x5b731b8>, 'utf8', None)
```

I guess the error comes from this `<function ...` statement. Is that the reason for the error? What kind of expression is that? It's hard to google `<`.

Comment: You cut the traceback. Can you add the last line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The:

```
<function read_blankline_block at 0x5b731b8>
```

Is *not* an expression, it's simply how python represents functions as strings:

```
>>> def my_function(): pass
... 
>>> my_function
<function my_function at 0x12c05f0>
```

So, since you do not want to use a different function, simply leave it alone.

You could instantiate the `TaggedCorpusReader` in this way, using keywords argument:

```
TaggedCorpusReader('.' ,  filelist, '/', 
        WhitespaceTokenizer(ur'\s+', True, True, 56), 
        RegexpTokenizer('n', True, True, 56), 
        encoding='utf8')
```

If you want to pass a function as argument simply use the identifier:

```
TaggedCorpusReader('.' ,  filelist, '/', 
        WhitespaceTokenizer(u'\s+', True, True, 56), 
        RegexpTokenizer('n', True, True, 56), 
        some_function_name, 
        'utf8', None)
```

Comment: Ty, Sir, your comment was really helpful. Are such function representations common in python documentations? If yes, why?

Comment: @smoes It depends. Probably nltk uses some automated tool(probably sphinx) to generate the documentation, which uses the string representation of default values. If the documentation is not automatically generated then you wont see such things.